# Sorting an ArrayList in Java with Strings and Integers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Strings in Java. All strings have the format [Integer] [String]. For example:

`100 Tom Dsa 
 23 John Asdf

 98 Mary Qwerty`

I want to sort this ArrayList by the Integer. The correct output would be:

`23 John Asdf 
 98 Mary Qwerty 
 100 Tom Dsa`

Right now, I'm using the following code:

`Collections.sort(obj);`

The problem with it is that interprets the integer as a string, therefore 100 is sorted before 2.

Is there any way of sorting this correctly?

Comment: You can define you own comparator implementation and then pass it to the sort method.

Comment: That List of Strings probably should become a List of some other class that encapsulates that number with first and last name in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One approach:** You could write a custom `Comparator` which scan int value from String using `java.util.Scanner` and compare them as bellow:

```
Collections.sort(obj, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return new Scanner(s1).nextInt() - new Scanner(s2).nextInt();
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** it is safe to use `Scanner` to parse `Integer` when there may be few leading space exists as bellow:

`"        98 Mary Qwerty"`

instead of `"98 Mary Qwerty"`

Answer (score 2):

If the elements in the List always be like Integer and String delimited by space you can use below

```
    Collections.sort(obj, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return Integer.parseInt(s1.split("\\s+")[0]) -  Integer.parseInt(s2.split("\\s+")[0]);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    for (String string : obj) {
        String key = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(" "));
        map.put(Integer.valueOf(key),
                string.substring(key.length(), string.length()));
    }
    obj.clear();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        obj.add(entry.getKey().toString()+entry.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println(obj);
```

OUTPUT::

[23 John Asdf, 98 Mary Qwerty, 100 Tom Dsa]